# Java - different parameters resulting to different outputs

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I want to achieve the following:

If I call the method v2.horn() with either parameter a or b, it should output either a or b. But somehow I can't find out how to do it.

Code is below:

```
public class Vehicle {
    int maxSpeed;
    int wheels;
    String color;
    double fuelCapacity;  

    void horn(a,b) {
        String a = "Beep!";
        String b = "Boop!";
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    void blink() {
        System.out.println("I'm blinking!");
    }
}

class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle();
        Vehicle v2 = new Vehicle();
        v1.color = "red";
        v2.horn(a);
        v1.blink();
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not even compile?

Comment: This has nothing to do with parameters. You are missing [basic OOP understanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) in general.

Comment: it is a two parameter method, you can not call it using one argument.

Comment: My question was how to output either a or b. But noone can give me an answer nor a explanation?

Comment: @Dop4miN because it would seem you do not read the comments.

Comment: Even if you fix the compile errors, you still assign `a` and `b` to text, so you're better off passing one variable, a `String`, pass the value `a` or `b` and have an `if` in the method to print depending on if `a` or `b` was passed, and perhaps something if neither was.

Comment: Why are you even passing parameters in horn function if you are not going to use it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're trying to achieve is that when you call your method "horn" with some parameter it has to either use "Beep!" or "Boop!".

First of:

```
void horn(a,b)
```

Is not a valid function signature in Java, in a java function you always have to specify what type the input you're providing is.

In your function you'd have to define that a and b are String like so:

```
void horn(String a, String b)
```

If you'd want your code to function in the way you wrote it right now you'd have to move your code a little bit and you'd end up with this:

```
public class Vehicle {
int maxSpeed;
int wheels;
String color;
double fuelCapacity;

void horn(String in) {
    System.out.println(in);
}

void blink() {
    System.out.println("I'm blinking!");
}
}

class MyClass {
public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    String a = "Beep!";
    String b = "Boop!"; 

    Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle();
    Vehicle v2 = new Vehicle();
    v1.color = "red";
    v2.horn(a);
    v1.blink();
    }
}
```

An other way to achieve the functionality you're looking for: You could also just use a boolean.

```
void horn(boolean a) {
    if (a)
    {
        System.out.println("Beep!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Boop!");
    }
}
```

Then in order to do what you wanted to do you'd have to call the method like this:

```
// Use either true or false.
v2.horn(true); 
v2.horn(false);
```